# Timestamp Issue in php

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have two strings.
A date.
And a Time.

I concatenate the two strings together, parse with Carbon and save into my database like this:

```
$ticket->date = Carbon::parse($date." ".$time);
$ticket->save();
```

Now I logged the values before saving and this is what I got for the concatenated string:

```
2017-07-29 04:00 PM
```

This is what I got after Carbon:parse():

```
{"date":"2017-07-29 16:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}
```

However after saving I check my database and this is the value that has been stored:

```
2017-07-29 09:00:00
```

I cannot figure out what is happening or what I am doing wrong, I even tried changing the timezone from the PHP but that didn't work either.

Comment: mysql and timestamp